# What is the best way to update a calculated derived column during Slowly dimension update?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, nested-sets

I'm working on a SSIS project to build a datawarehouse.

Here is my simple SSIS process built to load a dimension table (Locations).
Location table contains a parent/child structure based on Nested sets (LEFT,RIGHT, LEVEL fields).
So, Insert process works as well as update process.

[image]

However, I need to fill a calculated column (PARENT_ID) in order to store the parent relationship.
So, for each row I need to use (LEFT, RIGHT and LEVEL columns) in a SQL statement to find the PARENT_ID value).

This is table structure of the source table :
[image]

So what is the best way to populate my parent_id column during loading process ?
Should I build a dedicated data flow to this process ?

Can I use a SQL statement in a Derived column component to find the parent_id value ?

**EDIT** : Here is my SQL query to update my parent/child structure (parent_id field).

```
UPDATE 
    L1
    SET L1.[PARENT_ID] = (
    SELECT TOP 1 L2.ID
           FROM [DW].[DimLocation] L2
           WHERE L2.[TREE_LEFT_VALUE] < L1.[TREE_LEFT_VALUE] AND L2.[TREE_RIGHT_VALUE] > L1.[TREE_RIGHT_VALUE]    
           ORDER BY L2.[TREE_RIGHT_VALUE]-L1.[TREE_RIGHT_VALUE] ASC)
FROM [DW].[DimLocation] L1
WHERE [TREE_LEFT_VALUE] > 1
```

**EDIT 2**: Here is a diagram to represent a Nested Set structure and how to represent it in a database.
[image]
[image]

So, each node contains  `TREE_LEFT_VALUE` and `TREE_RIGHT_VALUE` values that respectively bound their childs `TREE_LEFT_VALUE`/`TREE_RIGHT_VALUE` values.

It's made to find in a simple query all children of a specified node. For example if I want all children of the "ROOT 1" node, i need to query all nodes where `TREE_LEFT_VALUE` is more than 2 and `TREE_RIGHT_VALUE` less than 5.

Because I need to use parent_id structure in my datawarehouse (SSAS project to build an OLAP cube), I need to update a PARENT_ID field by adding the parent node ID. So, I need to query the parent node ID by using `TREE_LEFT_VALUE` and `TREE_RIGHT_VALUE` fields then to use the result in a update statement.

It works fine, but is there a more efficient way to do that ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column is nullable, I would update it with a SQL task after your data flow.  This will insure that all possible parent rows are inserted before you try to find the parentid - also, it will keep the process set based, rather than trying to do it with a lookup in a dataflow task.

Comment: I added my SQL query to update the parent_id field. It works fine, but is there a more efficient way to do that ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the table structure well enough to answer that question.  Ideally, you would not have a subquery to get the value for each row.  That is definitely going to slow it down.  If you provide the table structure and explain how the records relate to each other more explicitly, that would help.  i.e. I don't know what Tree_left_value means exactly.

Comment: I hope my second edit will help you to understand my problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  For the particular requirement, I don't think that you can write the query any more efficiently.  I would consider the indexes and also add to the where clause not to update the row with the same value.  Avoiding unnecessary updates will help.